# How do I update the sld of layer dynamically

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, sld

I am using Geoserver 2.1.3 and Openlayers2.3. I have set the default sld for each layer in geoserver which it take by default on map startup, but when I update the sld using code

```
map.layers[3].mergeNewParams({SLD:"http://'localhost':8080/geoserver/www/mapstyles/simpleRoads.sld" });
map.layers[3].redraw();             
map.layers[4].mergeNewParams({ SLD : "http://'localhost':8080/geoserver/www/mapstyles/Them1.sld" });
map.layers[4].params.styles =  sld.namedLayers["banks"].userStyles[0];
map.layers[4].redraw();
```

nothing happens except a blink to both layers.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how long your request is, but there are a few tricks to get it shorter.

- Because SLD involves so much repetition with the tags, using a global namespace in the root tag (`xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld"`) and not repeating `<sld:Tag>` every time will save you a lot of character.
- if you generate the style dynamically, there should not be any unnecessary white spaces, but you can check that too.
- different browsers might accept longer url, so check with something else than IE, if not done yet.
- the only time this happened to me was when I had a scale-dependent symbology, with the same filters and parameters being repeated for different scales, but with different values. For this, you can regenerate the style for each scale, only generating the style for the specific scale
- an alternative would be to split you request in two. you call twice your layer, with different style and when they overlaps it is a complete style (this just a trick to see if your style parameters work, but it is not advised).

EDIT
You can also tried to change the parameter that limits the size of the URL on the server side. On my Tomcat 7 installtion it is: `maxHttpHeaderSize`. You find in in `server.xml`.

```
 <Connector port="8080" maxHttpHeaderSize="65536" protocol="HTTP/1.1" ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this and it worked.

I attached the function newstyle() to a click event. My layer name was global.

```
function newstyle() {
    console.log('newstyle');
    cities.mergeNewParams({"styles": "cc_cities_etj"});

}
```

Comment: my problem is that when ithe sld becomes large it gives the GET error, any idea how to overcome this Thanks

Comment: My first thought is the url is too long. Are you sending the name of sld defined on your geoserver, or are you sending a style defined in the map? Can you post the url?

Comment: no i m creating the sld in my javascript at runtime by accepting parameters from users and yes the url is getting too long for get request.